# next(h) TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator

Tags: python

This block code gives me this error 'TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator'. I can't find the issue because I have a nearly identical program which works just fine.

```
else:
     v3=r
     for h in range(0,len(oddnums)):

         if v1+v2+v3+v4==totalvals:
             temp=[v1,v2,v3,v4]
             combinations.append(temp)
         else:
           next(h)
           print()
```

Here is the full source code:
       global oddnums
       global temp
       global combicount
       global fcombinations
       global ecount
       global totalvals
       global lrem
       global v4

```
 for i in range (0 ,len(oddnums)):
     v1=oddnums[i]
     if i>=totalvals:
         next(i)
         print()
     else:
         print("v1")
#print(v1)
     for x in range (0,len(oddnums)):
         v2=oddnums[x]
         print('v2')
         total=x+i
         if total >=totalvals:
          next(x)
         print()
     else:
      rem=totalvals-(x+i)
     if rem<4:
         next(x)
         print()
     else:
         print()

     for r in range (0,len(oddnums)):

         #print('v3')
         count += 1
         #print(count)

         lrem = rem - oddnums[r]
         if lrem<1:
            next(r)
            print('no val')
         else:
             v3=r
             for h in range(0,len(oddnums)):

                 if v1+v2+v3+v4==totalvals:
                     temp=[v1,v2,v3,v4]
                     combinations.append(temp)
                 else:
                   next(h)
                   print()
 my_method()
```

Full error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
hello
  File "C:/Users/willf/Documents/Transition Task/question1/src/com/companyBoolean/4waycombo.py", line 92, in 
v1
    my_method()
v2

File "C:/Users/willf/Documents/Transition Task/question1/src/com/companyBoolean/4waycombo.py", line 84, in my_method
    next(h)
TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is trying to use `next(i)` and `next(x)`. `i` and `x` are integers produced by the `range` iterator, not iterators themselves.

Change those lines to `continue` and you should be fine.

Comment: Except that [`range` is not an iterator](http://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/).

Comment: @DYZ, Right, by "`range` iterator" I mean the iterator produced by the `range` object. A useful distinction to make just the same, though, so thanks.

Comment: Well, `range` does not produce an iterator. It produces an iterable. You may want to read the blog post by the link I provided, it may be an eye-opener :)

Comment: No, I understand the difference. `range` is a class, calling it (`range(10)` or whatever) gets you a `range` *object*. Calling `__iter__()` on the *object* instance produces an instance of `range_iterator`. That `range_iterator` object, which is an iterator produced by the `range` object, is what I mean when I say the `range` iterator.

Comment: It is produced _from_ the range object, not _by_ the range object. Once again, `range` has no more to do with iterators than any other iterable. You wouldn't say "a tuple produces an iterator"?

Comment: Sure, in the context of explaining Python iterators I would certainly say that `(1,2,3).__iter__()` produces an iterator object. From PEP 234 - Iterators: "Looping is customized by providing a method that produces an iterator object." That aside, I feel like I've adequately explained that I was not calling `range` an iterator but using "`range` iterator" to designate the iterator produced/made/returned when a `range` object's `__iter__` method is called.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 else:
     next(h)
     print()
```

`next()` gets the next item of an *iterator*. Since h is an `int`, it can't be iterated over.

You don't need to use `next()` in a for loop, because for loops iterate without other code (h will increase each time the loop is run).